# How to find whole word only in JtextPane

Tags: java, string, swing, awt

I have to find out whole word only in a given text.I had tried that.But,it is not working sometimes.For example whole word contains starting of a given text as a substring,end of the given text contains the whole word and I press search button continueosly It was shows an error "offset out of bounds" in some cases.Please help me.Thank you in Advance.

Here is my code:

```
    public class FindWholeWord extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FindWholeWord().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JTextField searchText;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane textPane;
    private javax.swing.JButton search;

    public FindWholeWord() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void highLight(JTextComponent component, String patteren) {
        try {
            Document doc = component.getDocument();
            String text = component.getText(0, doc.getLength());
            int pos = component.getCaretPosition();
            if (pos == doc.getLength()) {
                pos = 0;
            }
            int index = text.toUpperCase().indexOf(patteren.toUpperCase(), pos);
            int start = Utilities.getWordStart(component, index);
            int end = Utilities.getWordEnd(component, index + patteren.length());

            int patterenLn=patteren.length();
            int diff=end-start;
            if (index >= 0) {
                if((start==index)&&(end==index+patterenLn+1)){
                component.setSelectionStart(index);
                component.setSelectionEnd(index + patteren.length());
                component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        search = new javax.swing.JButton();
        searchText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        textPane = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        searchText.setText("test");
        textPane.setText("test qweqw test asdasdas test");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        search.setText("Search");
        search.setFocusable(false);
        search.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                searchActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(search, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addComponent(searchText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(114, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(scrollPane)
                .addContainerGap()));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(search)
                .addComponent(searchText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 235, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        highLight(textPane, searchText.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jens `javax.swing.text.Utilities` ;)

Comment: start with code "How to search in JTextComponents" from Official Oracle tutorial

Comment: note issue about performance was asked and answered here in last month

Comment: Please keep code snippets *short* and explain the actual problem, what you've tried and what exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems with you indexing when you are searching, to start with, you don't check to see if the result of `indexOf` is `-1` until after you've tried using the value; if the matching word is at the end of the document, it won't return a match, etc...

Rather than trying patch it, I re-wrote it instead...

```
public void highLight(JTextComponent component, String patteren) {
    try {
        Document doc = component.getDocument();
        String text = component.getText(0, doc.getLength());
        int pos = component.getCaretPosition();
        boolean found = false;
        int findLength = patteren.length();
        // Rest the search position if we're at the end of the document
        if (pos + findLength > doc.getLength()) {
            pos = 0;
        }
        while (pos + findLength <= doc.getLength()) {
            // Extract the text from teh docuemnt
            String match = doc.getText(pos, findLength).toLowerCase();
            // Check to see if it matches or request
            if (match.equals(patteren)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            pos++;
        }

        if (found) {
            component.setSelectionStart(pos);
            component.setSelectionEnd(pos + patteren.length());
            component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Updated**

To enable check for "whole" words, one would simply need to check the preceeding and following characters for a space.  The trick would be preventing it from over running the end of the `Document`...

```
if (match.equals(patteren)) {
    if (pos - 1 >= 0 && 
            doc.getText(pos - 1, 1).equals(" ")) {
        if (pos + findLength == doc.getLength() ||
                doc.getText(pos + findLength, 1).equals(" ")) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated with more aggressive white space checking**

```
if (match.equals(patteren)) {
    if (pos - 1 >= 0
            && Character.isWhitespace(doc.getText(pos - 1, 1).charAt(0))) {
        if (pos + findLength == doc.getLength()
                || Character.isWhitespace(doc.getText(pos + findLength, 1).charAt(0))) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to search whole word only.for example given text is " testcase something test anything test".Highlight only the test two times.I dont want to highlight the test in testcase.You take this text and check it my program then you can understand my problem easily.thank you for your response.

Comment: Okay, see how you can modify the matching `if` statement to meet that requirement

Comment: I had tried this program with the following test "testcase dsfbr test hfgbr test
hdgfrhd testcase fgd test
rejhge herbgur test".It will not highlight the all "test".Please check it once.Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you only want whole word matches, the it works find.  It matches each `" test "` in the `String` you provided

Comment: Try the following "testcase dsfbr test hfgbr(here \n)
test hdgfrhd testcase(here \n)
 fgd test rejhge herbgur test".Cpmment shows single line.That's I put newline.The given text is in three lines.Please try it and reply me.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a regular expression?

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?i)" + pattern + "\\b").matcher(text);
while (matcher.find(pos)) {
  component.setSelectionStart(matcher.start());
  component.setSelectionEnd(matcher.end());
  component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
  break;
}
```

Comment: It's fine.But,This was not check the end of word space.

Answer (score 0):

Run This code - Handled -1 index value.

```
    public class Trial extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Trial().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JTextField searchText;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane textPane;
    private javax.swing.JButton search;

    public Trial() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void highLight(JTextComponent component, String patteren) {
        try {
            Document doc = component.getDocument();
            String text = component.getText(0, doc.getLength());
            int pos = component.getCaretPosition();
            if (pos == doc.getLength()) {
                pos = 0;
            }
            int index = text.toUpperCase().indexOf(patteren.toUpperCase(), pos);
            int start = 0;
            int end = 0;

            if(index>=0){
            start=Utilities.getWordStart(component, index);
            end=Utilities.getWordEnd(component, index + patteren.length());
            int patterenLn=patteren.length();
            int diff=end-start;
            if (index >= 0) {
                if((start==index)&&(end==index+patterenLn+1)){
                component.setSelectionStart(index);
                component.setSelectionEnd(index + patteren.length());
                component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(component, "Word Not FOund");
        }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        search = new javax.swing.JButton();
        searchText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        textPane = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        searchText.setText("test");
        textPane.setText("test qweqw test asdasdas test");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        search.setText("Search");
        search.setFocusable(false);
        search.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                searchActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(search, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addComponent(searchText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(114, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(scrollPane)
                .addContainerGap()));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(search)
                .addComponent(searchText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 235, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        highLight(textPane, searchText.getText());
    }
    }
```